# nuxt does not ignore folder when doing build

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I want to ignore the `amplify` folder in my app, but it keeps rebuilding.

I have tried inside nuxt.config.js:

```
extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    exclude: /amplify/,
  })
},
```

Or i my tsconfig.json folder:

```
"exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist", "amplify/"]
```

But if i change something inside `amplify` and do a `npm run generate` it still writes:

> Doing webpack rebuild because
> amplify/backend/function/testdata/src/index.ts modified

How do i ignore this directory?

Comment: Try `nitro.prerender.routes` = `['/amplify']` in `nuxt.config.js`, here is the [nuxt docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#generate) and [nitro docs](https://nitro.unjs.io/config#prerender)

Comment: @init-qy i forgot to say that i use nuxt 2.x

Comment: Nuxt 2 also has similar setting in `nuxt.config.js`, [docs](https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#exclude). You seems miss `generate` outter `exclude`.